# React Native: Background job not executing on some Android OS versions?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, background-process

I have tried to integrate the following npm packages regarding sending Push Notification:

- react-native-background-job
- react-native-background-fetch
- react-native-background-task

For Push Notifications:

- react-native-push-notification

The Notifications work fine in the foreground. The problem is that the background service does not run in certain Android OS. Take a look at the following code:

```js
// Imports
import BackgroundJob from 'react-native-background-job';
.
.

// Define the Job
const backgroundJob = {
  jobKey: "PNJob",
  job = () => {
  console.log("Running in Background!");
  // Execute Push Notification
  }
};


// Register Background Job
BackgroundJob.register(backgroundJob);

var backgroundSchedule = {
  jobKey: "PNJob",
  period: 1800000, // Interval every half Hour (in ms)
  timeout: 5000,
  requiresCharging: false,
  override: true,
  persist: true,
  // allowExecutionInForeground: true,
  allowWhileIdle: true,
  requiresDeviceIdle: false,
  // exact: true
};

// ***  Schedule  ***
BackgroundJob.schedule(backgroundSchedule)
  .then(() => console.log("The Job has been scheduled!"))
  .catch(() => console.log("There was a problem in scheduling"));
```

I've tried debugging several possible issues but there is still some underlying issue I can not place.

Comment: Does it work on some devices and doesn't on others ?

Comment: Exactly. And there isn't a solid reason for working on a device, it varies with OS version and the manufacturer (Samsung, Huawei etc).

Comment: Hi I think you can try [Background Geolocation](https://github.com/mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation) It works well with my case.